# Type assert uppercase interface to lower

Tags: typescript

In `C#` it is convention for class / interface properties to be uppercase. In `ts` & `js` this is not the case. So when we get data back from an ajax call it is normally uppercase.

So I have something like the following where I want to type assert between the two:

```
interface CSharp {
    B: string;
    A: string;
}

interface TS {
    a: string;
    b: string;
}

let cs: CSharp = { A: 'hello', B: 'bob' };
let ts: TS = cs as TS;
```

This fails, but is there a method in `ts` to achieve this without having to do manual property mapping between the two?

Comment: This is usually done on server side - just configure your json serializer to write in camelCase

Comment: @AlekseyL. Great suggestion! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is not. `as TS` is the type assertion, not type conversion. That means you let the compiler know that it is a `TS` type, not ask the compiler to transform it to a `TS` type, which is also not possible.

And basically, TypeScript helps you to verify your code, not transform your code. What you expected is a JS feature, which is to transform data, not type.

And if you don't want to change the configuration on the server, you can use this code

```
interface CSharp {
    B: string;
    A: string;
}

interface TS {
    a: string;
    b: string;
}

let cs: CSharp = { A: 'hello', B: 'bob' };
let ts: TS = Object.keys(cs).reduce((sum, key) => {
    sum[key.toLowerCase() as keyof TS] = cs[key as keyof CSharp];
    return sum;
}, <TS>{});
```

Hope that's clear enough